# Get LisItem from a List in a SPX Library componen Projext

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepointframework

i need to get list intem from a list, in a SPFX library component.
Anyone know how to do this? PNP js or SPHhtpClient;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the code demo to get List Items with SPHttpClient:

[Retrieve SharePoint list items using SharePoint framework (SPFx)](https://www.spguides.com/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework/)

PnP Js Demo:

[@pnp/sp/items](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/sp/docs/items/)

[Retrieve SharePoint list items using SharePoint framework (SPFx)](https://www.spguides.com/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework/)